# How to derive a ranking function by analysing feature correlations

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, ranking

I am analysing some employee details to find the efficiency of the employees. Ideally I want some rankings to rank them based on these features.

My features include;

- current salary
- projects completed
- customer ratings
- number of bugs reported
- customer complaints
- employee satisfaction
- profit
- age
- etc.

My target is the `ranking` of the employee in the job hierarchy.

I did some correlation analysis and found some features that have positive correlation (e.g., salary, projects completed, profit, customer ratings, employee satisfaction etc.).

I also found some features that are negatively correlated with `ranking` (e.g., customer complaints, number of bugs reported etc.)

Now, I want to use these features to make a function that reflects the `employees actual rankings`, so that we can use the same function to rank employees in the future.

**NOTE: I am not only limited to `correlations`. I am happy to receive answers using other methods as well.**

Is there a any good method to solve my problem.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: I guess principal component factor analysis will be used somewhere. Based on those variables, run a PCA and use the first loading to rank the students.

Comment: Please indicate measurement- types numeric for different "features" you want to incude. in your  measure of efficiency. how do you compute efficiecy?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I want some ranking (i.e. the most efficient employee to be 1 and so on). Do you have any suggestions? :)

Comment: kindly respond  to clarificatios if you want an approrate answer from  the users of this accredoted site.

Comment: Do you have an external measure of the efficiency of a worker? If not, do you know in advance which "pole" of _every_ of your features is positive ("efficient")?

Comment: @ttnphns No, I do not have any external measures of workers. In most of my features highest value assume to be more efficient. However, there are some features such as `customer complaints, number of bugs reported` which are better when the employee has a lower score. Do you have any suggestions? Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: As already suggested to you, that seems to an undertaking of factor analysis or at least PCA. That will allow you to construct few (maybe one or two or three) latent constructs (dimensions) of "efficiency", the kinds of efficiency. If your features are not all interval scale but some are categorical, then this is a problem, but you could try CatPCA or other approaches ([read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/215404/3277)). You should first read literature on these kind of analysis for it is not quite easy.

Comment: It sounds like you might already have known target ranks for each employee. Is this the case? And, are you trying to learn a ranking function that matches these targets? If that's the case, could you edit the question to make this clear?

Comment: @user20160 Thank you for the comment. Yes, I do have target ranks for this year. However, our intention is to make a ranking function that we can use in future (more specifically yearly) to rank the employees. Please kindly let me know if you have any suggestions :)